# spark RDD sort by two values

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

I have a `RDD`of `(name:String, popularity:Int, rank:Int)`. I want to sort this by `rank` and if `rank` matches then by `popularity`. I am doing so by two transformations.

```
var result = myRDD
        .sortBy(_._2, ascending = false)
        .sortBy(_._3, ascending = false)
        .take(10)
```

Can I do the it in one transformation?

Comment: Cant you convert RDD in to dataframe and sort like this df.orderBy(desc("foo"), "bar")

Comment: @RamPrasadG thanks for your suggestion. But I need RDD processing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try make an `RDD` of key value where key will be `Tuple` composed from `rank` and `popularity` and value will be `name` and sort by the key.

For example:

> // _._1 - name
>
> // _._2 - popularity
>
> // _._3 - rank

```
var tupledRDD = myRDD.map(line => ((line._3, line._2), line._1))
.sortBy(_._1, ascending=false)
.take(10)
```

Comment: correct, or just `myRDD.sortBy(line => (line._3, line._2), ascending=false)`

Comment: Thanks. It's working. I need to know how `sortBy()` is working. What if I want to use different combinations of ASC and DESC.

Comment: mistakenly clicked. thanks for notifying. @AvihooMamka